# What's a simple periodic function with a smooth curve?

Tags: algorithms, puzzle, curves, periodic-functions

Is there a simple way to produce a smooth repetitive oscillation, using just basic arithmetic expressions, without trig functions, powers, square roots, etc.?

The numbers don't have to mean anything or approximate anything, it should just plot to something wavy.

I've spent lots of time searching but can only find things like the Taylor series, Bézier curves, etc. which are fairly complex because they're trying to calculate something in particular rather than just produce something curvy.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(x\bmod 1)(1-(x\bmod 1))(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}.$$ You cannot spare the modulo.

[image]

Note that this *is* a quadratic Bezier curve.

Comment: Oooooops, typo.

Comment: Thanks. :) Wolfram link for the curious: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot:+(x+mod+1)(1%E2%88%92(x+mod+1))(pow(-1,+(floor(x))))

Comment: And sine approximation... https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot:+(4)(x%2Fpi+mod+1+)+(1%E2%88%92(x%2Fpi+mod+1))+(pow(-1,+(floor(x%2Fpi))))

Comment: Only problem is... that raising to the power of a non-integer :(

Comment: @DenverCoder9: which noninteger ?

Comment: x, as in ⌊x⌋ which the (-1) is raised by.

Comment: @DenverCoder9: hem, then where is the power of a noninteger ?

Comment: The -1 is being raised to the power of a non-integer. (As oppose to, say, being raised to the power of 2).

Comment: @DenverCoder9: hew, what do you think the floor (which you faithfully copied) is there for ?

Comment: Ah, of course *slaps forehead*. Sorry, not a mathematician. :)

Answer (score 3):

If the floor function bothers you, you can use
$$
(x\%2)*(x\%2\, - \,1)*(x\%2\, - \,2)
$$
Here $x\%2$ denotes $x$ mod 2. This is a string of cubic (Bezier) curves.

[image]

Comment: Cool. ObWolf: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot:+(x+mod+2)%E2%88%97((x+mod+2)+%E2%88%92+1)%E2%88%97((x+mod+2)+%E2%88%92+2)

Answer (score 1):

Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind wiggle up and down nicely. There are some pictures [on the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#First_kind).

They only require multiplication and addition.

If you want more wiggles, you can either increase the degree or string together several functions of lower degree.

If you want infinite wiggles that go on forever, you can construct periodic versions of the Chebyshev polynomials by using the `mod` function.

See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283473/wiggly-polynomials).