# Is it possible to generate a circle with a Bezier curve?

Tags: circles, bezier-curve

I am designing an algorithm that generates shapes of bezier curves. Each output are control points for a single curve.

In some cases, it should return a circle. Which control points does the algorithm have to output for the shape to become a circle?

Comment: Closely related to these two questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271319/polynomial-approximation-of-circle-or-ellipse  and  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449035/is-it-possible-to-build-a-circle-with-quadratic-bezier-curves?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is not possible draw a perfect circle with Bézier curves, but the approximation is good enough. See [How to create circle with Bézier curves?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734745/how-to-create-circle-with-bezier-curves) and [Approximate a circle with cubic Bézier curves](http://spencermortensen.com/articles/bezier-circle/).

Comment: Well, isn't surprising because the circle has a rational parametrization: http://mathnow.wordpress.com/2009/11/06/a-rational-parameterization-of-the-unit-circle/.

Answer (score 4):

Without using rational Bezier curves, drawing a circle is impossible. I remember I had to prove that once for some class I had, and the proof isn't pretty.

However, drawing the circle using rational bezier curves is quite easy, as I recall. Take the points $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$ and $(0,1)$ and weights $1,\frac{\sqrt2}{2}, 1$ (I'm not sure, the middle weight may also be $\sqrt2$) and you get a circle.

Comment: do you still remember the proof or a sketch of it?