# draw a circle using beizer curve and co-ordinate of control points

Tags: circles, bezier-curve

I want to draw a circle of radius R centered at the origin using Bezier Curve Segments. I have to draw the circle using four Bezier Curve segments - one for each quadrant as shown in the following figure .

[image]

How can I find the co-ordinate of four control points for each of the Bezier curve segments ? The basis matrix for Bezier curve is as follows :

$ 
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 3 & -3 & 1 \\
3 & -6 & 3 & 1 \\
-3 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
 $

Comment: It's not possible to draw a perfect circle with Bézier curves, but you can get pretty close. See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/754435/856 and http://spencermortensen.com/articles/bezier-circle/

Comment: The distance between each "circular" dot and its adjacent "square" one should be 0.551915024494. All other coordinates are obvious, I suspect.