# Calculate control points of cubic bezier curve approximating a part of a circle

Tags: bezier-curve

I'm not mathematically inclined, so please be patient with my question.

Given

- $(x_0, y_0)$ and $(x_1, y_1)$ as the endpoints of a cubic Bezier curve.
- $(c_x, c_y)$ and r as the centerpoint and the radius of a circle.
- $(x_0, y_0)$ and $(x_1, y_1)$ are on the circle.
- if it makes the calculation simpler, it's safe to assume the arc is less than or equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

How do I calculate the two control points of the Bezier curve that best fits the arc of the circle from $(x_0, y_0)$ to $(x_1, y_1)$?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let $(x,y)^R=(-y,x)$ represent rotation by $\pi/2$ counterclockwise and
$$
\gamma(t)=(1-t)^3p_0+3t(1-t)^2p_1+3t^2(1-t)p_2+t^3p_3
$$
define a cubic bezier with control points $\{p_0,p_1,p_2,p_3\}$.

Suppose $p_0=(x_0,y_0)$, $p_3=(x_1,y_1)$, and $c=(c_x,c_y)$ are given so that $|p_0-c|=|p_3-c|=r$ ($p_3$ is counterclockwise from $p_0$). Then $p_1=p_0+\alpha(p_0-c)^R$ and $p_2=p_3-\alpha(p_3-c)^R$ where
$$
\alpha=\frac43\tan\left(\frac14\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{(p_0-c)\cdot(p_3-c)}{r^2}\right)\right)
$$
For a quarter of a circle, $\alpha=\frac43(\sqrt2-1)$, and $\gamma$ is no more than $0.00027$ of the radius of the circle off.

Here is a plot of $\gamma$ in red over the quarter circle in black. We really don't see the circle since it is no more than $0.1$ pixels off from $\gamma$ when the radius is $400$ pixels.

$\hspace{3.5cm}$[image]

---

**Computation of $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$**

Looking at an arc with an angle of $\theta=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{(p_0-c)\cdot(p_3-c)}{r^2}\right)$

$\hspace{1.5cm}$[image]

we see that the distance from $c$ to the middle of the arc is
$$
r\cos(\theta/2)+\frac34\alpha r\sin(\theta/2)
$$
we wish to choose $\alpha$ so that this is equal to $r$. Solving for $\alpha$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
\alpha
&=\frac43\frac{1-\cos(\theta/2)}{\sin(\theta/2)}\\
&=\frac43\tan(\theta/4)
\end{align}
$$

---

**A Slight Improvement**

Using a circle of radius $1$, the maximum error in radius produced using $\alpha=\frac43\tan(\theta/4)$ is approximately
$$
0.0741\cos^4(\theta/4)\tan^6(\theta/4)
$$
and the error is always positive; that is, the cubic spline never passes inside the circle. Reducing $\alpha$ reduces the midpoint distance by $\frac34\sin(\theta/2)=\frac32\tan(\theta/4)\cos^2(\theta/4)$ times as much, so to distribute the error evenly between the positive and negative, a first guess, assuming that the amplitude of the radius is unchanged, would be to reduce $\alpha$ by $0.0247\cos^2(\theta/4)\tan^5(\theta/4)$.

A bit of investigation shows that, when equalizing the positive and negative swings of the radius, the amplitude increases and that
$$
\alpha=\frac43\tan(\theta/4)-0.03552442\cos^2(\theta/4)\tan^5(\theta/4)
$$
gives pretty even distribution of the error between positive and negative for $\theta\le\pi/2$. The maximum error, both positive and negative, is approximately
$$
0.0533\cos^4(\theta/4)\tan^6(\theta/4)
$$
When $\theta=\pi/2$, this agrees with [the article](http://spencermortensen.com/articles/bezier-circle/) mentioned by bubba in comments.

Note however, that in minimizing the radial error from the circle, the actual variation in radius is increased. Using the simple formula for $\alpha$, which puts the cubic bezier outside the circle, the radius varies by $0.0741\cos^4(\theta/4)\tan^6(\theta/4)$. However, when we minimize the error, the radial variation increases to $0.1066\cos^4(\theta/4)\tan^6(\theta/4)$.

Comment: This is a very good approximation of a circular arc, and it's the one that's most often used. However, it produces a curve that is everywhere outside the true circular arc. You can get a slightly better approximation by reducing the length of $\alpha$. In fact, the error for a unit radius quarter circle is reduced from 0.00027 to 0.00019. The details are here: http://spencermortensen.com/articles/bezier-circle/

Comment: @bubba: the image in that article is 72 pixels in radius. Using the $\alpha=\frac43(\sqrt2-1)$ would yield a maximum error of $\frac1{500}$ of a pixel, so I don't think the error from either approximation would be noticeable.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: @bubba: I have added a section in which I adjust $\alpha$ so that the positive and negative errors are equalized.

Comment: Nice. I agree that the accuracy of the original approximation would be fine for almost all applications. To get better approximations, you can apply the same sort of equi-oscillatory construction with higher degree polynomials (though it gets much harder). The accepted answer to this question has the details: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271319/polynomial-approximation-of-circle-or-ellipse

Comment: > Would the downvoter care to comment. Despite my (slightly) negative comment, is wasn't me. In fact, I was an up-voter.

Comment: @bubba: I see that you have asked some good questions in the same topic. Only rarely have I known someone who has downvoted to comment; most likely, fear of retribution. I didn't think you were the downvoter. In any case, the downvote has been taken back. I would still be interested to find out what was perceived to be wrong.

Comment: Can we use the above approximation to construct the approximated offset curve to the Cubic Bezier Curve?

Comment: In the next comment, I'll post a Sage script that creates a plot comparing the vertical error (rather than the radial error) for a quarter circle arc, for various values of alpha: 'mid': the Bézier curve touches the midpoint of the arc, 'mort': Mortensen's value that minimizes radial drift, 'area': the curve and arc have equal area, from me22's answer. (You can test additional values by appending them to the `params` dictionary).

Comment: [Plot script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJw9kN1ygyAQhe95ip3eCA7JiD_VZMYncWKHREys-FNAm6bTdy9gWm4OO99y9iwGSli5woEJCNK2YDuDZq744IpvBBAMXRPAEaJ9lsVxkebpoUii_JBQDydlgg2yA8uiOE2zhBXMQ64E_4N5bp_mRZSmrwVFP-g8T_LLjqh0nVBIQhPqOvaXOg41BVMnJ9SIFtplvOCeHK0hwGxcrAozGhEKVnonPWVOIisn33YWD9umlwEvEMIqLmZSeCXQTgoWukI3wqObsc9AnSkh_p2fh83tOc2dOwUX0zpiU1ryD5Qwixot3IH-UAaz3b2ON_xELUL6Nn3iWU4GV889fIbeJdh-eb9yuQiNyclvAHYT6yHFVYzNm-RnIcsq3Fptx1V1jexGocuXgb9P6oWQXwBveUE=&lang=sage)

Comment: What does α represent?

Comment: @FMaz008: Looking at the diagram, $\alpha$ is the scaled distance between the extreme control points and the interior control points.

Comment: @robjohn I'm just wayyy below your level. I was hoping for the answer to go: a = (formula) x0= (formula \* a), y0= (formula \* a), x1=(formula \* a), y1=(formula \* a)

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want. Formulas such as those are given in the second paragraph. e.g. $$\alpha=\frac43\tan\left(\frac14\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{(p_0-c)\cdot(p_3-c)}{r^2}\right)\right)$$

Comment: @robjohn. Could you clarify which points you are refering to when you say " extreme control points and the interior control points" Is the interior point the one on the circle ((x0,y0) and (x1,y1)) and the extreme points the " two control points of the Bezier curve" the OP was asking for, or something else ? 

I guess I'm just trying to figure how you get ControlPoint1.x = ? ControlPoint1.y = ?, ControlPoint2.x = ? ControlPoint2.y = ?

... markE probably figured out how to get there, but I'm struggling a bit more to make the link apparently

Comment: If you look at [Bézier Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve), [the first diagram](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d0/Bezier_curve.svg/440px-Bezier_curve.svg.png) is of a cubic bezier curve. The curve is given by $$\gamma(t)=P_0(1-t)^3+3P_1t(1-t)^2+3P_2t^2(1-t)+P_3t^3$$ where the $P_k$ are the control points. $P_0$ and $P_3$ are the extreme control points and $P_1$ and $P_2$ are the interior control points.

Answer (score 3):

As a different way to choose where the error falls, one could pick the control points such that the *enclosed area* matches that of the circle.

If we consider the first quarter of a circle (the same as the first image in the other answer), then the area should be $\pi/4$, so we need the integral

$$
\begin{align}
\pi/4 
  &= \int_{0}^{1} y(t)x'(t)dt \\
  &= \int_{0}^{1} ( (1-t)^3 + 3(1-t)^2t + 3(1-t)t^2c )( 3(1-t)^2c + 6(1-t)t(1-c) ) dt \\
  &= -\frac{3c^2}{20}+\frac{3c}{5} + \frac12 \\
c &= 2 - \sqrt{\frac13(22-5\pi)} \\
  &≈ 0.5517784778...
\end{align}
$$

That's slightly smaller than the [other two answers](https://spencermortensen.com/articles/bezier-circle/), as it attempts to even out the error between over- and under-shooting the circle, rather than minimizing the maximum error.

*Aside: Edits appreciated to add a solution for angles other than 90°.  My maths are rusty.*

Comment: You may like to look at the plot script I posted in a [comment on robjohn's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873224/calculate-control-points-of-cubic-bezier-curve-approximating-a-part-of-a-circle/873589#comment8675883_873589).

Comment: Your answer is the closest to [the `0.551784777779014` that a class in the .NET Framework uses](https://github.com/dotnet/Microsoft.Maui.Graphics/blob/9294a8c8d87db7e08330d2c33174a0b455c01fdc/src/Microsoft.Maui.Graphics/PathF.cs#L10) for what they call the "ideal ratio of cubic Bezier points for a quarter circle." Many other repos on GitHub also use that magic value.

Comment: @LouisWaweru Tracing the git history to the PR, <https://github.com/dotnet/Microsoft.Maui.Graphics/pull/269#issuecomment-1017111301> says that number came from <https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#circles_cubic>, which appears to get it from a python binary search that tries to minimize the average error for t ∈ {⅕, ⅖, ⅗, ⅘}.  I'm not sure why just those, but the page calls the improvements "essentially insignificant", so I don't think it was too concerned about getting really the best answer, just something that doesn't always overshoot when the constant can be hard-coded.

Answer (score 0):

I got inspired to attempt yet another way to interpret "best fit": most-constrained *curvature*.

Let's look at the first quarter-circle, using the four control points  $<1,0>$, $<1,α>$, $<α,1>$, $<1,0>$.

$$
\begin{align}
x(t) 
  &= (1-t)^3 +  3 (1-t)^2 t + 3 α (1-t) t^2 \\
y(t)
  &= 3 α (1-t)^2 t + 3 (1-t) t^2 + t^3 \\
  &= x(1-t) \\
k(t)
  &= \frac{ x' y'' - y' x'' }{ (x'^2 + y'^2)^{3/2} } \\
  &= \frac{ -18(2α(t - 1)t + αt^2 - 2(t - 1)t)(2α(t - 1) + αt - 2t + 1) + 18(α(t - 1)^2 + 2α(t - 1)t - 2(t - 1)t)(α(t - 1) + 2αt - 2t + 1) }
          { 27((α(t - 1)^2 + 2α(t - 1)t - 2(t - 1)t)^2 + (2α(t - 1)t + αt^2 - 2(t - 1)t)^2)^{3/2} }
\end{align}
$$

Where $k(t)$ is the *signed* curvature, but since we're going clockwise it'll be positive.

As is usually the case, the curvature expression is horrible, so we need a more tractable way forward.

Thinking about the extreme cases, a lower value of $α$ (like $0.1$) will make the ends turn sharply to get a flat middle while a high value of $α$ (like $1$) will make flat ends thus causing a pointy middle.

Graphing the curvature for a few values of $t$ helps confirm that intuition ([source](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx1UktugzAQ3UfKHUbKwjZ1EgxNNxWrHiNKKic4EYIAAieC7nuIHqP7dtMD9BA9SWdwyKcficEz8958_OSDrjhLmYS42Okkj1hldMbE_XAwHKzMU2KqkFsJpY-m0AK0UEAEXI2tWIZe6cMNhJ71XCLwSuUS6HYprwwwYYkaDgcNdUupwUV31X2pBJ8GtydKwxWMwUWjywK_Y1OZ23RUZoXl8665mgZCQnt210XNrVcmXVAneR8sJBx7KQQyszV5_JjplcmiOWuYZC0aFuMfq9hC0KQ62eYmfthXB233lSEhIE42G95IwLt2bitpZytw91N8hJoeEjC9qlySSGc2hmLJQ9yShrrb_RjNSYTuRtdpNb37D7j9G_AnMwJIj9TpMZn9VsRGPj4TPL6eX5zz8XY83xnW6sbUjlwj-_OVsHU_gwj1WmcmYrXZJVmxRXGh3eGLmyhydBMpX3wDliq5XA==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==))
[image: curvature for various values of t]

($t > 1/2$ not included on the chart due to symmetry.)

Since we're approximating a unit circle we're hoping to get $k(t) ≈ 1$, and those lines seem to intersect around there, at roughly $t ≈ 0.55$.

To balance out the extremes, we can pick $α$ such that ends and the middle have the same curvature.  To avoid weird curves we'll require $α \in (0, 1)$, which simplifies a few things

$$
\begin{align}
k(0) = k(1) &= k(1/2) \\
\frac{-2(α-1)}{3α^2} &= \frac{ 8\sqrt{2} α }{ 3(α-2)^2 } \\
{-2 (α-1) }{ 3(α-2)^2 } &= { 8\sqrt{2} α }{3α^2} \\
α &≈ 0.550581172753306
\end{align}
$$

That value gives curvature within about $±1\%$ for $t \in [0, 1]$ ([source](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx9UktugzAQ3SNxB0tZ2KZOYuO6iVSx6rJHiJKKBCdCoQSBE0FXPU33vUgP0ZN0bOdDqrQSg2bmzZs3M3BIa4K3mKFs95rmZYJrnRaYPoZBGCz1W65rSQxDFQcTYDGYpChBRAwNXcio4ugOychEPhFHlfAJcF0qqmJIGFsqw6C13ba2Qa-7cM-WIW6Fu3NJSwQaIh8N-gTuqi3NTzqoip0hM9dcjGPKUHdxV7uGmKjKXdDk5SmYM3TsJQAo9EaX2UuRLnWRzHCLGe7AgAxvYOE5tUpNvil19rSvD6nZ19oeAmX5ek1ahmBX53bMzmwozH6Oj1B7gigaXzEX9kiXagjpgkiY0n-IxjyDFB8pxdVUiEk8UVLyhzDwi_-ayq01UvfKLXwLUvw25JT-Zqn_j_b1mVhV-Ju8q3jPVdPv949LrDC0SlvdeHYDdGPR1UkTDv4DnGG6FA==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==))
[image]

*Exercise for the reader*: Convince a CAS to compute

$$
\int_0^1 (k(t) - 1)^2 \mathrm{d}t
$$

or

$$
\int_0^1 log(k(t))^2 \mathrm{d}t
$$

and find the value of $α$ that actually minimizes the error in curvature -- it probably gives a slightly different value from the one I computed here.