# Approximating an arc with NURBS

Tags: circles, spline

I am trying to find a way to approximate an arbitrary arc (given by an angle phi and a radius) with a degree 3 NURBS (ie at least 4 control points).
This website: https://www.ibiblio.org/e-notes/Splines/nurbs.html

gives a method for degree 2 NURBS, just applying a weight of cos(phi) to the inner control point. Is there a way to generalize this method to any degree ?

Comment: In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/873589), cubic bezier approximations of circular arcs are computed.

Comment: The website you refer to is not to create an approximation for an arc. It is an exact representation of an arc as a rational quadratic Bezier curve. If you want it to be of any degree, you can perform degree elevation on the Bezier curve.